# Bounded real-valued function on $[0,1]$, non integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral, brownian-motion

Does such a function exist? If yes, it must be a very pathological case. I am talking here about Lebesgue integrability.

For instance, if $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and zero otherwise, then $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$. So you need to find an example more pathological than that. A possible example is the following.

Let $f(x)$ be the realization of a Gaussian random variable $Z_x$ with mean equal to $0$ and variance equal to $1$. Let us assume that the $Z_x$'s are identically and independently distributed. Such a function $f(x)$ is nowhere continuous, and can be seen as the realization of a white noise. However, you could argue that its integral on $[0,t]$ is the value $B(t)$ of a realization of a Brownian motion starting with $B(0)=0$, and measured at time $t$. Thus $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = B(1)$. Note that Brownian motions are nowhere differentiable, so maybe there is a contradiction in what I am saying here.

Anyway, I've never found counter-examples: a function bounded on $[0, 1]$ but not integrable in that interval. Can you show an example?

Comment: The standard example is to take a [non-measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) and consider the function which is 1 on the set and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: The problem with your iid Gaussian example is that when you go to define all those random variables on a probability space (set with a $\sigma$-algebra and a measure), you find that the set of outcomes $\omega$ for which $x \mapsto Z_x(\omega)$ is integrable, is not in the $\sigma$-algebra, so you cannot even *ask* whether the integral exists.

Comment: Getting off the subject, but "iid Gaussian function" is really not the right definition of "white noise".  It should instead be a process which is not actually a function of time but rather a distribution.

Comment: Any bounded measurable function is integrable so one needs non-measurable functions hence one needs the axiom choice etc

Comment: @NateEldredge Do you happen to have a reference for that claim about iid Gaussian random variables?

Comment: @Mdoc: Not offhand, but the idea is that the only reasonable probability space to use is $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ with its product $\sigma$-algebra.  A set is in this $\sigma$-algebra only if, roughly speaking, you can tell when an element $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is in it by looking at $f(x)$ for countably many $x$.  And you can't tell whether a function is Lebesgue measurable from countably many of its values.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for that great intuition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[0,1]$.

Either $f$ is measurable, and then
$$
\int_0^1 |f| ≤ \sup |f|\ \int_0^1 1\,\mathrm d x = \sup |f| < \infty
$$
so $f$ is integrable.

Either $f$ is not measurable. This exists iff you assume assume the axiom of choice. You can then take any non measurable set $\Omega$ and take $f = \chi_\Omega$ the characteristic function of this set, as suggested by Nate Eldredge. Then by definition, this function is not integrable.